# Using Stokes' Theorem to solve a problem

Tags: calculus, integration, stokes-theorem

I am working on this problem:

> Use Stoke's Theorem to evaluate $\int_CF\bullet dr$. $C$ is the boundary of the portion of the paraboloid $x=y^2+z^2$ with $x\geq 4$, n to the back, $F= \langle yz,y-4,2xy \rangle$.

I know that Stokes' Theorem states: $$\int_{\partial S}F(x,y,z)\bullet dr=\iint_S(\nabla \times F)\bullet ndS$$
I found $\nabla\times F$. According to my calculations it is $\langle 2x,-y,-z \rangle$. The only thing is that I am completely forgetting how to find **n**. I feel like this should be pretty simple - but I cannot figure out how to do it. Can anybody help me figure that out?

Also, once I find **n** and finish figuring out the integrand, how do I figure out the limits of integration? Do I change it to cylindrical coordinates and do a double integral or a triple integral?

Also, I don't understand what this is finding - is it the flux?

I'm sorry if that was too many questions for one question. Thank you for your help!

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\boldsymbol{n}$ is the unit normal vector to the surface. To find it, you need to parametrise the paraboloid with two parameters, say $u$ and $v$, as $\boldsymbol{r}(u,v)$, and then the normal will be \begin{equation*}\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{r}}{\partial v}\end{equation*}
Your limits of integration will be determined by the ranges for the parameters $u$ and $v$ to cover the whole paraboloid.

Finally, yes, Stokes' theorem is used to relate the flux integral over a surface to the line integral around its boundary. So you can see it as finding the flux.

Comment: So can I do $z=r^2$? And then $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$?

Comment: I think you mean $x=r^2$, then $y=r\cos\theta$ and $z = r\sin\theta$, since you gave the equation $x=y^2+z^2$.

Comment: True. Then my n would be gotten from $<2r,\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)>\times<0,-r\sin(\theta),r\cos(\theta)>$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.